# SQLite получить следующую запись, если это последняя то получить первую

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3

У меня есть 3 таблицы.

Таблица с тренировками:

```
CREATE TABLE `training_session` (
`_id`   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`date_time` TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`training_day_id`   INTEGER,
`duration`  INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(`training_day_id`) REFERENCES `training_program_day`(`_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

Таблица с днями тренировочной программы

```
CREATE TABLE `training_program_day` (
`_id`   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`name`  TEXT NOT NULL,
`program_id`    INTEGER,
`number`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(`program_id`) REFERENCES `training_program`(`_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Таблица с тренировочными программами

```
CREATE TABLE `training_program` (
`_id`   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`name`  INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

В таблице с тренировочными днями есть столбец `number` который определяет каким по счёту идёт этот тренировочный день в программе. Из таблицы тренировок я получаю `number` последнего тренировочного дня:

```
SELECT tpd.number
FROM training_session AS ts 
LEFT JOIN training_program_day AS tpd ON ts.training_day_id = tpd._id
WHERE ts.training_day_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ts.date_time
DESC LIMIT 1
```

Я хочу получить данные по следующему тренировочному дню, поэтому использую код выше как подзапрос и нахожу тренировочный день, чей `number` на 1 больше.

```
SELECT 
tp.name AS program,
tpd.name AS training_day
FROM training_program_day AS tpd
LEFT JOIN training_program AS tp ON tpd.program_id = tp._id
WHERE tpd.number = 1 + (SELECT tpd.number
    FROM training_session AS ts 
    LEFT JOIN training_program_day AS tpd ON ts.training_day_id = tpd._id
    WHERE ts.training_day_id IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY ts.date_time
    DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Этот запрос работает правильно если `number` найденного в подзапросе дня не является наибольшим в таблице `training_prorgam_day`. Разумеется в противном случае ничего не возвращается. Но дни в тренировочной программе должны образовывать цикл, и поэтому я хочу, чтобы для наибольшего `number` возвращались данные по первому дню в программе. Но я не знаю как это сделать.
Я совсем недавно начал изучать SQLite и поэтому не знаю всех его возможностей. Не удивлюсь если вы скажете, что мой запрос не эффективен, буду очень благодарен за предложенную оптимизацию.

Например в таблицах содержатся следующие данные:

[image: Тренировки]

[image: Дни тренировочных программ]

[image: Тренировочные программы]

Я хочу получить следующее:

[image: Результат]

Comment: Самое простое, заверните подзапрос в еще один подзапрос. `select coalesce(max(number), 0) from (SELECT tpd.number .... limit 1)`. max вернет запись в любом случае, даже если ее нет. Но если нет - то вернет null, который coalesce превратит в 0 (или в -1 если счет идет с нуля)

Comment: @Mike Попробовал написать по вашему совету, но оно не работает, видимо я что-то не понял. Можете прислать полный код запроса?

Comment: @Mike Вот мой запрос:
`SELECT tp.name, tpd.name, tpd._id
FROM training_session AS ts
LEFT JOIN training_program_day AS tpd ON ts.training_day_id = tpd._id
LEFT JOIN training_program AS tp ON tpd.program_id = tp._id
WHERE number = (
 SELECT coalesce(max(number), 0)
 FROM(
  SELECT
  tpd.number
  FROM training_program_day AS tpd
  WHERE tpd.number = 1 + (
   SELECT tpd.number
   FROM training_session AS ts
   LEFT JOIN training_program_day AS tpd ON ts.training_day_id = tpd._id
   WHERE ts.training_day_id IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY ts.date_time
   DESC LIMIT 1
  )
 )
)`

Answer (score 0):

Запрос вроде работает, но мне кажется, что его можно написать проще и более эффективно. Жду рекомендаций по оптимизации.

```
-- 4) Находим данные по нужному нам дню
SELECT tp.name AS prog_name, tpd4.name AS day_name, tpd4._id AS day_id
FROM (
  -- 3) Если такого дня нет, берём первый день из этой программы
  SELECT 
  last_prog_id,
  ifnull(last_number_plus_1, 1) AS desired_number
  FROM (
    -- 2) Ищем тренировочный день из той же программы, чей номер на 1 больше
    SELECT
    last_prog_id,
    tpd2.number AS last_number_plus_1
    FROM (
      -- 1) Находим тренировочный день, по которому тренировались в последний раз
      SELECT
      tpd1.program_id AS last_prog_id,
      tpd1.number AS last_number
      FROM training_session AS ts 
      LEFT JOIN training_program_day AS tpd1 ON ts.training_day_id = tpd1._id
      WHERE ts.training_day_id IS NOT NULL 
      ORDER BY ts.date_time 
      DESC LIMIT 1
    )
    LEFT JOIN training_program_day AS tpd2
    ON last_prog_id = tpd2.program_id AND last_number + 1 = tpd2.number
  )
  LEFT JOIN training_program_day AS tpd3
  ON last_prog_id = tpd3.program_id AND last_number_plus_1 = tpd3.number
)
INNER JOIN training_program_day AS tpd4
ON last_prog_id = tpd4.program_id AND desired_number = tpd4.number
INNER JOIN training_program AS tp
ON last_prog_id = tp._id
```